# docker file arg variable not passed for asp.net core on linux

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have an Asp.Net core 3.1 app which is dockerized for linux  like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base 
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "Api/Authentication/Authentication.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api/Authentication"
RUN dotnet build "Authentication.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Authentication.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Authentication.dll"]
```

In the Azure Devops pipeline the build tempelate looks like this.
[image]

But the build fails with the following message

> ##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet build "Authentication.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build' returned a non-zero code: 1

The Arg BUILD_CONFIGURATION seems is not accepting the value from the devops piplline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ARG instruction goes out of scope at the end of the build stage where it was defined. To use an arg in multiple stages, each stage must include the ARG instruction. More information, you can refer to [ARG scope](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#scope)

So, you need to define **ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release** in build and publish stage.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base 
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "Api/Authentication/Authentication.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api/Authentication"
RUN dotnet build "Authentication.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "Authentication.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Authentication.dll"]
```